# Grouping usernames/emails in a data set

Tags: r, machine-learning, clustering, group-differences

I have a column in a dataset that is the 'user'. Can look like this:

- tom green
- tgreen
- tomgreen@here.com
- sam blue
- samtha green

How do i get this to group this so that the first three are grouped together and leaving the other two in their own groups. My initial naive approach was to use the hamming distance between all items in the list and then to group those under a certain limit together. It seems to work OKish but I was hoping there would be a better grouping algorithm to use.

Any pointer and help would be appreciated.

PS: I am doing this in R at the moment.

Comment: Hey. Why the down vote? If the question is not useful or not relevant then at least leave a comment so that I can fix it or know for the next time.

Comment: The strings are of different length - how are you calculating the Hamming distance between them? The Levenshtein distance suggested by @YCR - the least no. substitutions, insertions, & deletions to change one string to another - would be more appropriate than padding the shorter string. (I don't know why the down vote either.)

Comment: @Scortch, I was truncating them. I have started using the Levenshtein distance but the results are still a bit iffy.

Comment: Did you remove "@" & the host domain from e-mail addresses? How about changing the relative costs of substitutions vs insertions/deletions? I suppose better answers to this are going to make use of the structures within the strings: `forename + surname` / `initial + surname`, &c. Googling "parsing names" turns up some interesting-looking results.

Answer (score 3):

first, to improve the matching, you could work on your variable, for example deleting the @here.com.

Then, the software [open refine](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/Clustering-In-Depth)
 do this kind of clustering in a semi-automatic way. It does a cluster and allow you manually accept or reject the match.

Among the method implemented:

- Key Collision Methods
- Fingerprint
- N-Gram Fingerprint
- Phonetic Fingerprint
- Nearest Neighbor Methods
- Levenshtein Distance
- PPM

Another cool feature in open refine is the [reconciliation](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/Reconciliation) which use an exterior database(freebase) to help the matching.

If you want to assess the quality of your distance or take a mixed of both, you could match manually a sample of your dataset, apply multiple distances and see which is the best in your case. (or take a combination of multiple)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm not wanting to use an external application  at the moment.

Comment: Some of these methods are already implemented in r.